# SQL Query in a table but same id

Tags: sql, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

this [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3uka.jpg) is Lists on Sharepoint Database.

i Want to take data from database but i have version problem;

tp_ID is My List item ID 
tp_Version is My List Version

i want to take from data that higher version of tp_ID.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will give u exactly what u required :

```
select  * from (select  *,RANK () OVER ( PARTITION BY  tp_id ORDER BY   tp_version DESC) AS rnk
        from    yourtable
        ) mytable where rnk <= 1
```